# Responder chain - make UITableView don't scroll if the user scrolls on part of the cell

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, first-responder

So I have a cell, but there is one view in the `contentView` of the cell where I don't want the table to scroll if the user has scrolled.

So is this even possible?

According to the responder chain, the table would accept swipe event first and it will scroll and the other objects (cells) on the responder chain wouldn't receive the event at all.

So I want this - the table to check the cell that got the swipe, check if the part is the one that it can scroll and if it is just scroll. But if it's not then it must forward the event down to the cell.

Can somebody help me solve this?

Comment: So you have a tableview within a tableview?

Comment: Nope, just one table filled with cells